# Get parent's ID n-levels up when child is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html like this

```
<div id=longId class="container">
    <p> .. 
    <p> ..
    <ul>
      <li>
      <li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to get the ID of the div when any child in the class="container" div is clicked.

```
$(document).on("click", ".container", function(e) {
    var docnumber = e.target.id.split("-")[0];  //sometimes the children fire this. their IDs are not set
    var docname = e.target.id.replace(docnumber + "-", "");
    loadDoc(docnumber, docname);
});
```

I could ID each HTML element with appropriate ID (and parse them) or use jquery to loop up to a parent with an id of length greater than 1. But is there a clean way? I know that when you have the opposite problem (not firing parent when child is clicked) you can just stop propogation.

Comment: then why not: `var docnumber = this.id.split("-")[0];` ??? I'm not sure to understand the question

Comment: Since you are specifying the parent element `.container` your `this` variable will reference the div with that class. So `this.id` is the id of the div with class `container`

Comment: @A.Wolff: Given all the other convoluted answers, maybe you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I am so confused by the question and answers posted. Can't you just get the id of the div by this.id or $(this).attr('id')? your click handler will trigger if you clicked on the div or its children but this still refers to the div with the id you need

Comment: @FelixKling looks like it but i was not sure about the question, maybe too obvious...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with the closest function (http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(".container").on("click", "*", function(e) {
    var id = $(this).closest(".container").attr("id"); 
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Inside handler, `this` is refering to `.container` element, so use:

```
var docnumber = this.id.split("-")[0];
```

Comment: thank god someone answered this the simplest way, I don't know what's going on with the other answers

Comment: @Huangism i have see clearer question in the past, maybe that explains it... ;)

Answer (score 0):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/FC98L/)

```
$("*",".container").on("click",function(e){
   alert($(this).closest(".container").attr("id"));
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Bind an event handler to every descendant... really? Why not make use of the fact that events bubble?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", ".container *", function(e) {
    var element_with_id = $(this).closest('[id]');
    var docname = $(this).attr('id').replace(/^.*?-/, "");
    loadDoc(docnumber, docname);
    e.stopPropagation(); // Prevent bubbling up to higher elements
});
```